# CLion: Keyboard cmd to switch between header and implementation files like in xcode

Tags: clion

In xcode I type cmd-shift up/down to switch between .h and .c files. How do I do that in CLion? Or more usefully, what would that action be called in the keymap? I don't find the keymap names terribly usefully named. None stand out for this purpose, including after the usual googling.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The shortcut is called 'Related Symbol' in the keymap.
On Mac it defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>,
on Windows/Linux -- to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: Ubuntu running o a Mac: Ctrl + Alt + fn + Left

Comment: Does not work for me. Do .c and .h files have to be in the same folder?
I use CMake and my headers are in a separate `includes` directory. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 20):

To switch between .h and .c files I use F10 key or the Navigate menu in CLion in Linux system:

F10 Header/Source

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: It does not work in Ubuntu 18.04 because of the stupid system-wide Ubuntu shortcut

Comment: Aleksei Petrenko you can change this shortcut in Keymap option in Setting. My system is Debian 10, and Altgr+F10 it's free for this purpose.

Comment: Found my way here from the linked question regarding Android Studio. In Windows Android Studio 4.0.1 seems to support F10 as well (ctrl + alt + home works too, but pressing single key is much more convenient).

Answer (score 5):

you can try: Navigate | Related Symbol

Comment: This doesn't sound like an answer. If you're sure this works, kindly elaborate your point.

Answer (score 0):

If header and implementation files are already open you can switch between windows with double-shift and enter keys.

Comment: That switches to the last window, not between header and source.