# Is there a shortcut key to toggle h/cpp file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio v3.0 Beta 6 on Windows to edit C++ code and I'd like to know how to toggle (jump) between header (h, hpp) file and its corresponding CPP file. For example, using Visual Assist in Visual Studio, this is accomplished with `Alt + O`.

If this is not configurable by default in Android Studio, is there a plugin I can install that will enable this functionality?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+Home. Otherwise, search for "Related Symbol" in the keymap

Comment: Related questions: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33906528/1896169) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20682455/1896169)

Comment: @Justin Thanks, that does it. For others, this maps to the `Related Symbol...` command.

Comment: I know CLion is a different IDE altogether, but the Jetbrain IDEs are all very related. Maybe this shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of that, but idk